# Android: How to read stack traces which don't specify MY LINES of code

Tags: java, android, debugging, stack-trace, crash-reports

My app users are reporting errors which cause their stack traces to show up in Google Play Developer Console. But the problem is that several of these logs/traces do not include information about my app specific code.
Here's an example:

```
backtrace:
native: pc 0000000000069340    /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
native: pc 0000000000066ad0    /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+68)
native: pc 0000000000023910    /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
native: pc 000000000001e240    /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
native: pc 000000000000cf04    /system/lib64/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+236)
native: pc 000000000002c238    /system/lib64/libhwui.so
native: pc 00000000000288b8    /system/lib64/libhwui.so
native: pc 000000000002ae34    /system/lib64/libhwui.so
native: pc 000000000002f374    /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+124)
native: pc 00000000000169b4    /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+208)
native: pc 00000000000953c0    /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+96)
native: pc 0000000000016204    /system/lib64/libutils.so
native: pc 0000000000065f20    /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52)
native: pc 000000000001edec    /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

This is coming from a Galaxy S6.
Similarly, see the following trace:

```
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method:0)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:989)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This was also coming from Galaxy S6.
The following two came from Galaxy Tab4 7.0:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:741)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:278)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1067)
    at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:966)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(AppCompatPopupWindow.java:105)
    at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompatKitKat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompatKitKat.java:33)
    at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat$KitKatPopupWindowImpl.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:129)
    at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:206)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:721)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:160)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:803)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: 
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method:0)
    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:710)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:730)
```

and

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:741)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:278)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:478)
    at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.run(Toast.java:374)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: 
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method:0)
    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:710)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:730)
```

All these are coming from Samsung devices. I cannot reproduce these errors on my Nexus 5, nor are other devices users reporting these issues. How can I know what may have been causing the crashes?

I have one clue, but that, too only happening in Samsungs. I have the following code:

```
private class ListOldFiles extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

        ArrayList<String> filesList = loadOrderedCollection(FILES_LIST_KEY);
// loads JSON from SharedPreferences and converts it into ArrayList.
        for (String path : filesList) {
            if (isCancelled())
                return false;

            itemList.add(new Item(path));
            publishProgress();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        itemArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean shouldContinue) {
        if (shouldContinue)
            listAllFiles = new ListAllFiles().execute();

        super.onPostExecute(shouldContinue);
    }
}
```

On this code, the devices (samsung) are crashing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" at

```
             listAllFiles = new ListAllFiles().execute();
```

Comment: The reported error is "Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException". Probably your JSON is too big to be loaded. Have a look to the documentation about this exception for more information:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html

Comment: ok, the docs say "The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb". What does it mean? How reasonably large the JSON can be before it throws the exception?

Comment: I don't know what you try to achieve but you should probably find a better way to store your data if the JSON is too big. Maybe with a database or something. Like that you could request the only necessary information when the user is scrolling, instead of loading everything into memory.

Comment: I am saving the list of all audio files and then populating my RecyclerView with that saved list. In the mentioned AsyncTask, I am fetching it from the SharedPreferences

Comment: Yeah, basically you're loading into memory the entire list. So it's probably too big if the list of files is very long.

Comment: do you think that I should use sqlite? I personally don't like it but I think several apps use it for big data